# Android - Change READ_PHONE_STATE permission request message

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm using the Android Marshmallow READ_PHONE_STATE permission and I would like to change the text that appears on the permission request.

By default it shows:

> Allow [App name] to make and manage phone calls?

But I'm using it to get the `device id` and the `sim serial number`, so I think is better to change the request message. Do anyone knows how to do it (some special function or something)?

Or I just have to implement an independent `Dialog` for that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't change the text in the dialog. It is implemented by default in the system. You can provide a brief explanation regarding the permission before you ask for it. That way user will know exactly what you're going to use it for.

> Request Permissions
>
> If your app needs a dangerous permission that was listed in the app
>   manifest, it must ask the user to grant the permission. Android
>   provides several methods you can use to request a permission. Calling
>   these methods brings up a standard Android dialog, which you cannot
>   customize.
>
> Explain why the app needs permissions
>
> In some circumstances, you might want to help the user understand why
>   your app needs a permission. For example, if a user launches a
>   photography app, the user probably won't be surprised that the app
>   asks for permission to use the camera, but the user might not
>   understand why the app wants access to the user's location or
>   contacts. Before you request a permission, you should consider
>   providing an explanation to the user. Keep in mind that you don't want
>   to overwhelm the user with explanations; if you provide too many
>   explanations, the user might find the app frustrating and remove it.
>
> One approach you might use is to provide an explanation only if the
>   user has already turned down that permission request. If a user keeps
>   trying to use functionality that requires a permission, but keeps
>   turning down the permission request, that probably shows that the user
>   doesn't understand why the app needs the permission to provide that
>   functionality. In a situation like that, it's probably a good idea to
>   show an explanation.
>
> To help find situations where the user might need an explanation,
>   Android provides a utiltity method,
>   shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). This method returns true if
>   the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied
>   the request.

More details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)

Comment: I supposed I couldn´t. Thanks for the link.